# inside cassandraRDD no access to variables without a null pointer exception

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-2.0

I'm working on a standalone spark cluster (2 spark-master , 6 spark-worker)
spark v2.1.0 
com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector 2.0.0M3

I create a conf like this

```
val sparkConfiguration = sparkConf(master, appName).setAll(extraConf)
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConfiguration)
val cassConnec = CassandraConnector(sparkConfiguration)
val accEcriture=sparkContext.longAccumulator("accEcriture")
val accCompteur=sparkContext.longAccumulator("accCompteur")
```

Then I want to read a table in parallel with "n" cores

```
  sparkContext. cassandraTable(keyspace,aTable)
.foreachPartition {
  list =>
    list.foreach { 
      row =>
      // accessing an accumulator or a variable or sparkcontext generate NPE !!!
      accEcriture.add(1)
      accCompteur.add(1)
  }
}
```

It seems that inside a CassandraRDD, spark do not copy/broadcast variable 
I just see rows. In fact I need to use this parallel query to read and write in other cassandra tables.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace & also show the full code - do you run the `foreach` inside `main` function, or not?

Comment: yes it is in the main; any attempt to access an external variable fail with NPE

Comment: Can you show the full source code for it - object, function declaration, etc.?